# Laravel: Loading initial custom settings class

Tags: php, laravel, autoload

My aim is to fetch application concerned settings from a config file and load them to a DataSource and use it in the application. In the process of loading from the config file, I'd want to validate them and if they fail, Laravel should stop it's boot up. Sounds a bit a confusion, I guess. Hope the following example would help:

My config file `appSettings.php` is in `app/config`, just an example:

```
return array(
     'color' => '',
     'texture' => 'mixed',
     'layers' => 3
);
```

My DataSource class `DataSource.php` is in `source/DataSource.php`, just an example:

```
public class DataSource {
   public static function load() {
       if (Config::get('appSettings.color').empty()) {
           return false;
       }
       // Do other validations etc..
       return true;
   }

   public function getColorForRoom($roomId) {
       return something;
   }
}
```

Now, what is the right place for me to call the method `DataSource::load()`?. `DataSource` will be used in the application for fetching certain data like calling `getColorForRoom($roomId)` function.

Maybe in intializers or somewhere I could do:

```
if (!DataSource::load()) { 
    // Stop booting up Laravel
}
```

But I'm not sure where exactly to put this and how to stop the application from booting up.

**Possible Solutions**

I'm not sure if this can be the right way, but it seems like a good approach:

In my `bootstrap/start.php:`

```
require $app['path.base'] . '/app/source/DataSource.php';

if (!DataSource::load()) {
    Log::error("Failed to load datasource");
    throw new ApplicationBootException();
}
```

Again, I'm not entirely sure about this. Is this a bad solution or are there any other better solutions?

The other possible solutions are loading DataSource from routes or filters as mentioned in the below answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you throw a custom Exception? Then you can catch this exception and redirect to a view that is like a 404 but custom to your application?

```
public class DataSource {
   public static function load() {
       if (Config::get('appSettings.color').empty()) {
           throw new ApplicationBootException();
       }
       // Do other validations etc..
       return true;
   }
}
```

You could place this in the routes file.

```
App::error(function(ApplicationBootException $exception, $code){
    //.. your code here to handle the exception
});
```

Please note I am just using `ApplicationBootException` as an example. You would have to create this class and have it extend `Exception`

Comment: I do not think it stands relevant for the end user to know that there is a configuration issue. I would want the exception, if any, to logged into log files. The end user need not know about my configuration issues

Comment: In the code above where it says `//.. your code here to handle the exception` call the `Log::error()` method and then that will put it in the log. You just handle the exception there. You don't necessarily have to inform the user and load a view. If the configurations are absolutely necessary you may consider storing them in the .env file too

http://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#handling-errors

Answer (score 1):

Well - you could put it in the filters.php file

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (!DataSource::load()) { 
         App::abort(500, 'Config is not correctly set');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you reply :). It does not seem to be a good idea to do this is Filters. Filters are supposed to deal with request validations. But my requirement is a application configuration validation, which has to be taken care at a much lower level.

Comment: No - filters are not just request validations. `App::before` is designed to run on every request. If you want to check something on *every* request - this is where it goes.

Comment: Yes. Exactly my point. I do not want this to be checked on every request. Rather, only when the application is booting up. :)

Comment: The application 'boots up' on *every* request. There is no daemon service for PHP applications - each and every time you visit a web page the entire application runs from scratch. That is how PHP (and Laravel) are designed.